# How can a add acl rules for Oracle 11g to allow pl/sql upload file

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In Oracle 11g ,the database has an Fine-Grained network access control list, so when i use pl/sql to upload a file to the ftp_server,it gives me a network access error.

The error information like this:

```
  error at 1 line:
    ORA-29260: network error:not connected
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 212
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 432
    ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.FTP", line 413
    ORA-24247: Network access rejected by acl
    ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.FTP", line 491
    ORA-06512: at line 6
```

**I want to know how can i do about creating acl rules so that i can get the privilege.
Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/03/17/oracle-11g-access-control-list-and-ora-24247) a tutorial about ACL in Oracle.