# Oracle 11g ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, ora-24247

I am using  soap_api as in the link http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ConsumingWebServices9i.php. I was able to call a web service in

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Prod
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   10.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

But When i use the same in

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Its giving

```
"ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
 ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)"
```

Please help

Comment: Similar: [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875257/how-can-a-add-acl-rules-for-oracle-11g-to-allow-pl-sql-upload-file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875257/how-can-a-add-acl-rules-for-oracle-11g-to-allow-pl-sql-upload-file

Comment: Thanks.. My wsdl file is at http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9080/WesService/WebMethod/WebMethod.wsdl so what procedure i have to right ??

Comment: You have to add acl permissions to that xx.xxx.xx.xxx web address :) and to that specific port, or leave ports null then all ports are allowed to be used.

Comment: I am able to resolve this when i try to query(SP) by myself in query browser, But when the SP is executed via Advanced Queuing (which is called after insert trigger) its not working???

Comment: Have you tried to add ACL permissions? If so, please provide us the script which you used.

Comment: Sorry i dont have the script i gave the link to DBA he only executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle allows access to external network services using several PL/SQL APIs (UTL_TCP, UTL_SMTP, UTL_MAIL, UTL_HTTP and UTL_INADDR), all of which are implemented using the TCP protocol. You need to create one ACL (access control list ) for this. Bellow scripts may be useful in this case as worked for me . In my case : i am using SYS.UTL_HTTP to call one SOAP based web service from pl/sql level .

```
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
  acl          => 'networkacl.xml',
  description  => 'Allow Network Connectivity',
  principal    => 'PUBLIC',
  is_grant     => TRUE,
  privilege    => 'connect',
  start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  end_date     => NULL);
 dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
  acl         => 'networkacl.xml',
  host        => 'AS NEEDED*',
  lower_port  => AS NEEDED*,
  upper_port  => AS NEEDED*);
  commit;
end;
```

You may take a look : [here](http://gonithethinker.blogspot.com/2014/03/dbms-network-acl-of-hhtp-call-using.html)

- AS NEEDED = define yourself based on your requirement

Comment: That grants *every* database user the right to connect to *every* host on *every* port - seems kind of overkill and an outright invitation for DOS attacks.

Comment: I granted related principal but now I'm getting ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1415
do you have any suggestion? I also granted execution right on utl_http to my user